Change paraboloid vertex coordinate
The paraboloid equation
$x^2 + y^2$
It has its vertex at the point $x=0,y=0,z=0$.

How can I get the equation of a paraboiloid with its vertex at the point $x=2.4,y=2.4,z=0$?

You just need to perform a translation: $x\mapsto x-2.4$, $y\mapsto y-2.4$, giving $(x-2.4)^2+(y-2.4)^2$.

Just move the paraboloid  by (2.4,2.4)
so $z=(x-2.4)^2+(y-2.4)^2$

Thank you very much!
